# My AHK Image detection isn't doing what I want

Tags: autohotkey

So my code currently consists of

```
Loop
{
    CoordMode, Pixel, Window
    ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, 3440, 1440, C:\Users\MY_NAME\Pictures\PICTURE_TO_BE_FOUND.PNG
}
Until ErrorLevel = 0
If ErrorLevel
{
    Loop
    {
        Send, {Space}
        Sleep, 3000
    }
}
Else
{
    MsgBox, 48, Detection, Icon found, 2
    IfMsgBox, Timeout
    {
        Send, {Space}
        Sleep, 5000
    }
}
```

And for some reason my first Loop of pressing Space every 3000 milliseconds isn't doing anything when it doesn't detect the picture. Is it because the `ImageSearch` is in a Loop? Because it keeps searching and want to find it before continuing? If that's the case, how do I keep making it constantly look for the Image WHILE pressing Space every 3 seconds and then going to `Else` if it finds it?

Answer (score 1):

So I read your question as: *"how do I keep making it constantly look for the Image WHILE pressing Space every 3 seconds and then going to Else if it finds it?"*

This is what I would recommend:

```
CoordMode, Pixel, Window ; only needs to be set once per routine (until Return is found)
Loop
{
    ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, 3440, 1440, C:\Users\MY_NAME\Pictures\PICTURE_TO_BE_FOUND.PNG
    If ErrorLevel  ; not found the picture
    {
        Send, {Space}
        Sleep, 3000
    }
}
Until ErrorLevel = 0
MsgBox, 48, Detection, Icon found, 2
```